# filter rows by two out of three criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I want to filter a data frame such that I remove rows which hit two out of three criteria. My data looks like this:

```
    df <- structure(list(id = c("032", "033", "018", "052", "031", "072", "019", "071", "068", "999"), 
V1 = c(31.9, 76.3, 62.9, 23.6, 183.4, 114.8, 174.5, 74.9, 239.2, 19), 
V2= c(1.45, 1.03, 0.59, 1.25, 1.11, 1.64, 0.56, 0.64, 1.15, 0.84), 
V3 = c(60, 60, 50, 50, 50, 40, 60, 40, 30, 100)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to remove rows which hit 2 out of 3 of the following criteria:

V1 < 20;

V2 > 1.6;

V3 < 10 or > 90

In this example, the only corresponding entry is id = 999.

I've tried doing this by setting up a chain of filters to cover all possibilities, such as:

```
df |> 
filter(V1 > 20 & V2 < 1.6 | V3 > 10 | V3 < 90) |> 
filter(V2 < 1.6 & V1 > 20 | V3 > 10 | V3 < 90) |> 
filter(V3 > 10 | V3 < 90 & V1 > 20 | V2 < 1.6)
```

But the individual lines didn't succeed in filtering out id=999, and I also wonder if there's a way of doing this in fewer than three lines of code?

Comment: if you use `sum()` on a boolean vector it will effectively count the "TRUE"s, so if the sum is greater than 1 you have at least 2 out of 3 - try playing with something like `sum(V1 < 20, V2 > 1.6, V3 < 10, V3 > 90) >1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a matrix of these conditions and use `rowSums` to count how many of them are satisifed.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(rowSums(cbind(V1 < 20, V2 > 1.6, V3 < 10 , V3 > 90)) < 2)

#   id    V1   V2 V3
#1 032  31.9 1.45 60
#2 033  76.3 1.03 60
#3 018  62.9 0.59 50
#4 052  23.6 1.25 50
#5 031 183.4 1.11 50
#6 072 114.8 1.64 40
#7 019 174.5 0.56 60
#8 071  74.9 0.64 40
#9 068 239.2 1.15 30
```

This says that keep the rows that has less than 2 conditions satisfied.

Similarly, in base R -

```
subset(df, rowSums(cbind(V1 < 20, V2 > 1.6, V3 < 10 , V3 > 90)) < 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df |> 
filter(!(V1 < 20 & V2 > 1.6 | V1 < 20 & (V3 < 10 | V3 > 90) | V2 > 1.6 & (V3 < 10 | V3 > 90)))
```

First I made a filter that would filter the rows *with* the criteria that you wanted. Then I wrapped that in `(`parentheses`)` and put a `!` negation in front to do the opposite.